# How can I create reusable expression trees?

Tags: .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have this expression tree:

```
    internal static IEnumerable<ElemType> WhereIn<ElemType>(this IEnumerable<ElemType> query, string filterFieldName, string[] values)
    {
        ParameterExpression lambdaParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ElemType), "p");
        MethodCallExpression paramToString = Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(lambdaParam, filterFieldName), typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "Contains", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        Expression<Func<string[]>> array = () => values;
        MethodCallExpression contains = Expression.Call(mi, array.Body, paramToString);
        LambdaExpression lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<ElemType, bool>>(contains, lambdaParam);
        Func<ElemType, bool> lambda = (Func<ElemType, bool>)lambdaExp.Compile();

        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

Now, when calling it using something like `query.WhereIn("propName", new string[] {"aaa", "bbb"})` I don't always want the code to create a new expression tree as it's very time consuming to do this. But the `.Compile()` function doesn't come with parameters which would allow me to use a compiled lambda. (Or, rather, I just don't understand how to utilize it correctly.)

**How would the above expression tree needed to be rewritten to allow me to cache the compiled result and provide a string array to the resulting compiled lambda?**

Answer (score 0):

You should create and manage your own cache.
The key of the cache should be the property name.
The key concept is to create a a closure function with a reference to the array (curry function)
This is what you essentially need to create at runtime.
A function that gets the array and returns other function that matches the same parameters and return type of the linq where function.

```
public class ElemType
{
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Expression<Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>>> exp = (arr) => (ElemType et) => arr.Contains(et.MyProperty);
    var compiled = exp.Compile();
    var func = compiled(new[] { "aaa", "bbb" });

    var query = new List<ElemType> { 
        new ElemType { MyProperty = "aaa" }, 
        new ElemType { MyProperty = "bbb" }, 
        new ElemType { MyProperty = "cccc" } 
    };

    var result = query.Where("MyProperty", new[] { "aaa", "bbb" });
}
```

Entire solution of compiling the expression trees at runtime and using the property name as the key of the cache.

```
public class ElemType
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public static class ElemTypePropertySelector
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>>>();

    public static IEnumerable<ElemType> WhereIn(this IEnumerable<ElemType> query, string filterFieldName, string[] values) {
        var cachedFactory = GetOrAdd(filterFieldName);
        var contains = cachedFactory(values);

        return query.Where(contains);
    }

    private static Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>> GetOrAdd(string filterFieldName) {
        Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>> cachedFunc;

        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(filterFieldName, out cachedFunc)) {
            cachedFunc = CreateFactory(filterFieldName);
            dictionary.Add(filterFieldName, cachedFunc);
        }

        return cachedFunc;
    }

    private static Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>> CreateFactory(string filterFieldName) {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "Contains", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(ElemType).GetProperty(filterFieldName);
        ParameterExpression arrExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]), "arr");
        ParameterExpression rtParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ElemType), "et");
        var callExpression = Expression.Call(null, mi, new Expression[] { arrExpression, Expression.Property(rtParam, pi) });
        var innerExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ElemType, bool>>(callExpression, new[] { rtParam });
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string[], Func<ElemType, bool>>>(innerExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { arrExpression });

        return expression.Compile();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var query = new List<ElemType> { 
            new ElemType { MyProperty = "aaa" }, 
            new ElemType { MyProperty = "bbb" }, 
            new ElemType { MyProperty = "cccc" } 
        };

        var result = query.WhereIn("MyProperty", new[] { "aaa", "bbb" });
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll need some time to get through the sample code. Please bear with me.

Comment: In your CreateFactory you could construct the PropertyAccess expression, and then replce it in 
Expression<Func<string, string[], bool>> containsExpression = (val, arr) => arr.Contains(val);
with a parameter replace visitor. Its less code, and much more clear to read/edit

Answer (score 0):

What about [fast-member](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html)?
Then your method would be:

```
private static Func<string, string[], Func<ElemType, bool>> CreatePredicate() 
{
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(ElemType);
    return (fieldName, arr) => (elem => arr.Contains((string)accessor[elem, fieldName]);
}
```

and you can do:

```
var filterFactory = CreatePredicate()
query.Where(filterFactory("MyProperty", new[] { "aaa", "bbb" }));
```

Comment: This looks very intriguing! I'll have a deeper look at it.

Comment: If i understand correctly, i caches all these accessors, so you shuoldn't worry about performance. I have to say I just found it by searching a bit for dynamic property access with property name in variable, so I don't know this library, but it seems interesting.